# Running Adobe CS5 products under Administrator or Guest accounts in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, adobe-cs5

I can't run Adobe CS5 products like Photoshop, Flash or Dreamweaver under the Administrator or Guest accounts in Windows 7 Ultimate. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why do need to run it as an administrator?

Comment: why it can't be runs under administrator? for some purpose i need to work with Administrator account { for example to working VS 2010 with IIS 7.5 properly and haven't need to choose Run as Administrator for each time I'm using and ... }

Comment: Can you give us more information. Like what are you trying to do exactly? Just run the program and it won't start-up?

Comment: yes, exactly when i run program (Photoshop, Flash, Dreamweaver etc) that says: "Cannot use this product under aguest account". but works properly under another account

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by this:

- Create a new account as Administrator
- Run this program
- After that, erase the last account